# How to auto index rows in a BigQuery table?

Tags: indexing, google-bigquery

I am running a scheduled query that captures some changes in a dataset and log change on the daily basis into a Bigquery DataSet Table. I would like to be able to index each row on that table with an unique ID. This index would update each time new rows are added.

I am not sure how to achieve that. Can you throw me some clues? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "index"? 
Usually, in context of relational databases, this is something that allows to make filters and/or ordering faster.

Comment: I mean a unique ID per row. For instance I will have multiple events in the log for a same object in the source database. I would like to be able to point at specific instances of particular events. It can be a simple row count.

Comment: I don't understand your need.  Why not add [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#current_timestamp) to the scheduled query and then use that along with the existing key as a multi-column unique key.

Comment: @StevenEnsslen you’re right. I did that but it didn’t work, but I was mislead due to previous errors I made in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a unique column by adding [`GENERATE_UUID()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_uuid) as a column in your scheduled query.